# database view with recursive query?

Tags: sql, view

I need help creating a database view from the access_right table.

Here is an example of the data in it:

```
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+------+-------+
| id | user_id | business_id | parent_id | code | value |
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+------+-------+
|  1 |       1 |           1 | null      | A100 |     1 |
|  2 |       1 |           1 | 1         | A1   |     1 |
|  3 |       1 |           1 | 2         | A2   |     0 |
|  4 |       1 |           1 | 3         | A3   |     1 |
|  5 |       1 |           1 | 3         | A4   |     0 |
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+------+-------+
```

What I need to get:

```
+---------+-------------+------+----+----+----+----+
| user_id | business_id | A100 | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 |
+---------+-------------+------+----+----+----+----+
|       1 |           1 |    1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
+---------+-------------+------+----+----+----+----+
```

So, as you can see, I need to get the columns according to the value of code column and their status + in case one of the parents(recursively) is 0 I get 0.
Can you help mi solve this issue, please?

Comment: If the column names are supposed to be based on values in columns, then you cannot use a view -- in any database.  If the column names are fixed, then you can.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select user_id, business_id,
       max(case when code = 'A100' then value end) as a100,
       max(case when code = 'A1' then value end) as a1,
       max(case when code = 'A2' then value end) as a2,
       max(case when code = 'A3' then value end) as a3,
       max(case when code = 'A4' then value end) as a4
from t
group by user_id, business_id;
```

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, but how do I do if any of the parents is 0 I get 0?

Comment: @LukasBubo . . . I really don't see what the parent has to do with the question.

Comment: A3 and A4 should be 0 because their parent (A2) is 0, how to do this via parent_id ?